# How to convert string-vector into date-vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I need to convert a vector of strings into a vector of dates. I tried the following:

```
convertStringsToDate <- function(a) {
output <- c()
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
    output[i] <- as.POSIXct(a, format ="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
}
return (output);
}
```

The as.Posixct() part works when I feed it with a date-string. In the function below the output is a vector of 9 numbers, being not equal to the test-dates.

Furthermore, if the string contains milliseconds, are those converted as well. Do R-functions, that work with dates, consider milliseconds?

Comment: Type `?POSIXct` for all the gory details. I guess R does whatever is conventional.

Comment: You can start providing a sample data

Comment: @adiana: arg1 = c("2015-12-15T19:59:37Z"), inserted into the function results into > [1] 1450205977

Comment: Same problem exists with asDate():/

Comment: why are you looping over a when as.POSIXct is vectorised? You can just run as.POSIXct(a)

Comment: The returned value is the number of seconds since the beginning of time according to UNIX (Jan 1, 1970).  The function: as.POSIXlt(1450205977, origin="1970-01-01"), will return the a POSIXlt object.  @RichardTelford is correct, don't loop, but just vectorise it.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a vector of strings to a vector of dates without a for loop, and include milliseconds. Here is an example:

```
# Let's make simple vector of strings with in the form of: year-month-dayThour:minute:seconds.milliseconds
str_v <- c("2011-03-27T01:30:00.123", "2015-01-01T10:36:20.456")

dat_v <- as.POSIXct( str_v, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
# [1] "2011-03-27 01:30:00 CET" "2015-01-01 10:36:20 CET"

format(dat_v, "%F %H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "2011-03-27 01:30:00.122" "2015-01-01 10:36:20.456"
```

Comment: why use `sub`? `as.POSIXct(str_v, format = "%FT%T")` or eve `strptime(str_v,"%FT%T")`

Comment: This is a way that I find to include millisecond in the dates format.

Comment: Not really. To include the miliseconds you do not need the `sub` function. The format argument does that . ie `dat_v <- as.POSIXct( str_v, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")` then `strptime` or do the `format` as you did above

Comment: Not sure why I didn't replied to your comment at the time, but it seems I changed the main reply and removed the `sub` command. Good point, thanks!